# Use of 'which' to combine clauses

Tags: word-usage, syntactic-analysis, subordinate-clauses

Is there anything wrong, in terms of either grammar and/or usage, with the following sentence:
"The information age has ushered children into a global society, which is the cause of educators lamenting a lack of texts that explain the diversity of cultures."

Comment: It's ambiguous. Is the cause the global society, or is the cause the fact that the information age has ushered children into a global society?

Comment: _Which_ is not "combining clauses"; it's introducing a relative clause. Relative clauses can modify a noun phrase or a concept originating in a clause. As @PeterShor said, it's ambiguous.

Comment: "The information age has ushered children into a global society, which fact is the cause of educators lamenting a lack of texts that explain the diversity of cultures." OR "The information age has ushered children into a global society, which society is the cause of educators lamenting a lack of texts that explain the diversity of cultures."

Answer (score 1):

As Peter Shor, John Lawler, and Edwin Ashworth affirm, the sentence as originally structured doesn't make clear whether the cause of the educators' unease is "a global society" itself or the information age's ushering of children into that society. Once you've decided which meaning you're after, you can make the statement unambiguous by altering the sentence in a few minor ways.

*Case 1: "a global society" is the problem.* Here's an unambiguous way to express this idea:

> The information age has ushered children into a global society, and that society is causing educators to lament the lack of texts that explain the diversity of cultures.

*Case 2: the information age's ushering of children into a global society is the problem.* Here's an unambiguous way to express this idea:

> The information age has ushered children into a global society, prompting educators to lament the lack of texts that explain the diversity of cultures.

On the face of it, case 1 doesn't make much sense, so I would be very much surprised if case 2 weren't the idea that you wanted to convey.

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind thoughtfulness and illuminating response.